# Javascript submit not sending modified value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a javascript function that modifies the hidden value of a form depending on what button you click and then send it via post to a page that processes it.

I checked that the value is modified correctly, but when the post is sent the default value is sent.

Any help?

Here the js function:

```
function citar(key)
{
    document.getElementById('esta-cita').value=key;  
    document.getElementById('form-cita').submit();
}
```

**EDIT:** I did this and now it works. jQuery!

```
function citar(key)
{
    $("#ncita").attr("value", key);
    $('#form-cita').submit();
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns an HTMLCollection.

Comment: A snippet of the HTML might be helpful.

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns multiple elements, not just one.  You need to set the `value` of the one(s) you want.

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('esta-cita')[0].value=key;`

Comment: Could you provide some html

Comment: @DhavalMarthak: Assuming he wants the first one (which is a good assumption here).

Comment: I did that and `getElementById` as well but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please post your HTML. The DOM struction is very helpful in a question like this

Comment: @dabadaba mark question as solved. so we wont see it in open questions please. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem here is that you are using

> document.getElementsByName

which returns an array. Therefor the implementation of key is invalid. 
if you are using jQuery you might use

```
$('[name=esta-cita]').each(function() {
    $(this).val(key);    //this will insert key to all esta-cita named parameters, even if only 1
});
```

if you only have 1 parameter of this kind so :

```
 $('[name=esta-cita]').val(key);
    });
```

i deeply recommand you to use jQuery [jQuery website](http://jquery.com/)

in javascript's case i would have recommand you to use

> document.getElementById on 'esta-cita' as well.

if you want to insert key to all elements in javascript i would recommand a very efficient way :

```
document.getElementsByName('esta-cita').forEach(function(entry) {
entry.value = key; //entry indicates a cell in the array
```

Comment: I understand that, anyway when I used document.write(document.getElementsByName('esta-cita').value) the displayed result was correct so I was modifying the value correctly, just the sent value was the default one instead of the modified one.

Comment: jQuery is overhead for this sort of task. Not to mention it was not tagged in the question

Comment: @RUJordan this is why i included both answers, jQuery and Javascript. jQuery is for more advanced people but it is surely a better tool to work with.

Comment: I tried to use jQuery too and it worked, then saw this response. Thanks, this is the right answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try with,

```
document.getElementsByName('esta-cita')[0].value=key;
```

you can  access to a length property `document.getElementsByName('esta-cita').length` to know how many elements are matched

Alternatively you can try this

```
function citar(key)
{
  document.forms['form-cita'].esta-cita.value = key;
  document.forms['form-cita'].submit();

}
```

HTML should be like

```
 <form action="putActionHere" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-cita">
    <input type="hidden" name="esta-cita" id="esta-cita" value="yourval">
    ...
    <input type="submit"  value="Submit" onClick="citar('keystring');" />
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This returns an array of elements, so you'll have to iterate through it like a normal array.

```
function citar(key)
{
    document.getElementsByName('esta-cita').value=key;  
    document.getElementById('form-cita').submit();
}
```

Should be:

```
function citar(key)
{
    var derp = document.getElementsByName('esta-cita');
    for (var i=0;i<derp.length;i++) {
        derp[i].value = key;
    }
    document.getElementById('form-cita').submit();
}
```

Or just `document.getElementsByName('esta-cita')[0].value=key;` if you just want the first one

Comment: The sent value keeps being the default not the modified, new one.

Comment: Please post your HTML. I don't know if you're selecting inputs or anchor tags or something.